# I have to make a visual basic program that requests a year and gives a day of the week

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Alright I'm making a program that requests the user to input a year (2002 for example) and gives back the first Tuesday of that year.

I have no idea how to even begin this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use the `DateTime` type.

Comment: It's just a visual basic 2010 exercise problem. I can't figure out what to do with the date or how to use it. I have basic understanding of Visual Basic but using dates and finding a day of the week is giving me a lot of trouble. All it has to do is run properly when run in the vb studio.

Answer (score 2):

> I have no idea how to even begin this.

You being by thinking about how to solve this problem, without even thinking about code at first. You could think of some different approaches:

- Loop through the days of the year (starting with January 1st) until you find one that is Thursday
- Get the date of January 1st of that year. Check what day of the week it is. Add the number of days between this day of week and Thursday.

Now about the coding part: The  [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure is used to represent dates in .NET. A [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx) can be used to create a date for a specific day, month and year. If you take a look at the documentation for `DateTime`, you will find the [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) method which will be helpful for you.

I hope this will get you started!

**Edit:**

To convert user input (a string) into an integer, use the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) function.

Comment: The thing I'm having trouble with is just figuring out how to make the 4 digit year entry into something the program will understand as a year, then take the first day of that year, see if it is a Tuesday, if not depending on the day add something to it (if it is a Monday add 1 so it is now Tuesday, display that date), and if it is display that date. I think I know what I'm going to do with the rest of it but getting that first string value to be read as a year is what I can't figure out.

Comment: Yes, I didn't talk about that part. What you want to do is to `Parse` user input (a String) into an integer value. Then you can use this integer value to build a date for the first day of that year. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function GetFirstTuesday(year As Integer) As Date
    Dim d As Date = New Date(year, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 6
        If d.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday) Then
            Return d.AddDays(i)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving it using Linq (i'm linq beginner).
Errorhandling is up to you.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(GetFirstTuesdayOfYear(2013)) 'returns 01.01.2013
    Console.WriteLine(GetFirstTuesdayOfYear(2012)) 'returns 03.01.2012
    Console.WriteLine(GetFirstTuesdayOfYear(2011)) 'returns 04.01.2011
    Console.WriteLine(GetFirstTuesdayOfYear(2010)) 'returns 05.01.2010
    Console.WriteLine(GetFirstTuesdayOfYear(2009)) 'returns 06.01.2009
    Console.Read()
End Sub

Private Function GetFirstTuesdayOfYear(year As Integer) As DateTime
    Return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, 1)).[Select](Function(day) New DateTime(Year, 1, day)).ToList().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
End Function
```